# Why is this invalid EL expression?

Tags: java, jsf, el

I'm doing a simple logout and want to make sure i'm referencing correctly to the login root.

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandLink value="Logout" action="#{request.contextPath}/#{userController.logout()}" />
</h:form>
```

but i get this error:

```
/topnav.xhtml @16,104 action="#{request.contextPath}/#{userController.logout()}" Not a Valid Method Expression: #{request.contextPath}/#{userController.logout()}
```

UPDATE

Right now I'm adding navigation rules from the logout link to the login page and since the logout link is on all pages i need to add rules to allow the transition back to the login page. that seems like a lot of configuration for a simple item. would prefer to just have the method called indicate that the login page the the final destination and hot have to place a navigation entry from all pages to the login page.

Comment: You don't need to do that, the method expression already makes sure the right method is called.

Comment: I was hoping i could use this technique to control navigation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
<h:form>
  <h:commandLink value="Logout" action="#{userController.logout()}" />
</h:form>
```

beside the fact that you do not need context, you can not use `#` twice the way you are using it.

Comment: Fixing the code is not a good answer. It would be great if you could explain why you should make the change.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I would have thought that the line _beside the fact that you do not need context, you can not use # twice the way you are using it._ would have taken care of this objection :)

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation for [commandLink](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/commandLink.html):

```
Name      Required  Request-time    Type
==============================================================
action    false     false           javax.el.MethodExpression
```

The composite expression `#{request.contextPath}/#{userController.logout()}` cannot be resolved as a [MethodExpression](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/MethodExpression.html).

The [JSF 2.1 specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=314) says of MethodExpressions:

> *Method expressions* are a very similar to value expressions, but rather
>   than supporting the dynamic retrieval and setting of properties,
>   method expressions support the invocation (i.e. execution) of an
>   arbitrary public method of an arbitrary object, passing a specified
>   set of parameters, and returning the result from the called method (if
>   any).